How to reset a StackAPIError: 502, 'throttle_violation', 'too many requests from this IP, more requests available in 80678 seconds')
I need to reset a StackAPIError: ('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/sites/?pagesize=1000&page=1&filter=%21%2AL1%2AAY-85YllAr2%29', 502, 'throttle_violation', 'too many requests from this IP, more requests available in 80678 seconds').
I have tried different rate_limit settings and different time-delays before my fetches but still continue to get this error. I cannot continue to wait 24 hours for this error to clear to try another time delay setting to only get the error again. My question and answer fetches are shown below.
SITE = StackAPI('stackoverflow')
max_questions = 100

try:
    time.sleep(random.uniform(4, 7))  # Wait between 4 and 7 seconds to avoid StackAPIError: 502, Throttle Violation, Too Many Requests
    questions = SITE.fetch('questions', tagged='visual-studio', sort='votes', pagesize=max_questions, page=1, filter='withbody', rate_limit=2)

try:
    time.sleep(random.uniform(4, 7))  # Wait between 4 and 7 seconds to avoid StackAPIError: 502, Throttle Violation, Too Many Requests
    answer_data = SITE.fetch('answers/{ids}', ids=[accepted_answer_id], filter='withbody')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StackAPIError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-d81d4cee1371> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # Seed the faq_database
----> 2 scrape_faqs()

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/stackapi/stackapi.py in fetch(self, endpoint, page, key, filter, **kwargs)
    211                 code = response["error_name"]
    212                 message = response["error_message"]
--> 213                 raise StackAPIError(self._previous_call, error, code, message)
    214             except KeyError:
    215                 pass  # This means there is no error

StackAPIError: ('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/sites/?pagesize=1000&page=1&filter=%21%2AL1%2AAY-85YllAr2%29', 502, 'throttle_violation', 'too many requests from this IP, more requests available in 80678 seconds')


How frequently are you calling endpoints on this domain?

From what country are you making the calls? Is it a home connection or a server in the cloud? Could you try making calls from a different IP address?
